# Maximum distance between multiple location points in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection that every document has a location data point, like that:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("549adc5dbb4dd90200c9017d"),
"ts" : ISODate("2014-12-24T15:31:41.436Z"),
"location" : {
    "coordinates" : [ 
            42.366401, 
           -71.142170
        ],
        "type" : "Point"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to query this collection and get maximum distance between multiple location points?

for example if i have 3 documents with coordinates:

```
 1."coordinates" : [ 42.313187, -71.072182 ] 
 2."coordinates" : [ 42.313187, -71.084310 ] 
 3."coordinates" : [ 42.313187, -71.096410 ]
```

The result for this data will be 2 km.
because:

```
distance(1.,2.) = 1km
distance(2.,3.) = 1km
distance(1.,3.) = 2km
```

Comment: No - that's not presently a capability of MongoDB. You can find the furthest locations from a fixed location, and do that for each location in your documents, but that'd be pretty slow. Why do you want to compute the furthest distance?

Comment: My use case: i need to build a graph which the x axis shows days and the y axis shows the max distance between all the locations in that day.